# Postgresql. Merge and split date ranges from two tables by set of keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to combine multiple date ranges from two same tables with same or diferrent data. (PostgreSql 9.*)

**Tables structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE "first_activities" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('first_activities_id_seq'::regclass),
    "start_time" timestamptz,
    "end_time" timestamptz,
    "activity_type" int2,
    "user_id" int4
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "first_activities" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

CREATE TABLE "second_activities" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('second_activities_id_seq'::regclass),
    "start_time" timestamptz,
    "end_time" timestamptz,
    "activity_type" int2,
    "user_id" int4
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "second_activities" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

**Data in First table:**

```
INSERT INTO "first_activities" VALUES 
(NULL, '2014-10-31 01:00:00', '2014-10-31 02:00:00',  '3', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 02:00:00', '2014-10-31 03:00:00',  '4', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 03:00:00', '2014-10-31 04:00:00',  '2', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 04:30:00', '2014-10-31 05:00:00',  '3', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 05:30:00', '2014-11-01 06:00:00',  '4', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-11-01 06:30:00', '2014-11-01 07:00:00',  '2', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-11-01 07:30:00', '2014-11-01 08:00:00',  '1', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-11-01 08:00:00', '2014-11-01 09:00:00',  '3', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-11-01 09:00:00', '2014-11-02 10:00:00',  '4', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-08-27 10:00:00', '2014-08-27 11:00:00',  '2', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-08-27 11:00:00', '2014-08-27 12:00:00',  '1', '1'),
```

**Data in Second table:**

```
INSERT INTO "second_activities" VALUES 
(NULL, '2014-10-31 01:00:00', '2014-10-31 02:00:00',  '3', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 02:00:00', '2014-10-31 03:00:00',  '4', '1'),

-- Differece from first table
(NULL, '2014-10-31 03:30:00', '2014-10-31 04:00:00',  '1', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 04:25:00', '2014-10-31 04:35:00',  '3', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-10-31 04:45:00', '2014-10-31 05:35:00',  '3', '1'),
-- End of Difference from first table

(NULL, '2014-08-27 10:00:00', '2014-08-27 11:00:00',  '2', '1'),
(NULL, '2014-08-27 11:00:00', '2014-08-27 12:00:00',  '1', '1');
```

How can I filter result set that starting from query:

```
SELECT * FROM first_activities UNION ALL SELECT * from second_activities
ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

to get final result set.

**Final Result:**

```
-- merge same data by user_id and activity_type and combine with
-- and split data with range intersection but not same user_id and acitvity_type

-- start_time               end_time        type  user_id
'2014-10-31 01:00:00', '2014-10-31 02:00:00',  '3', '1');
'2014-10-31 02:00:00', '2014-10-31 03:00:00',  '4', '1');

--data dont merge. Splitting with range intersection
'2014-10-31 03:00:00', '2014-10-31 03:30:00',  '2', '1'); -- from first table
'2014-10-31 03:30:00', '2014-10-31 04:00:00',  '1', '1'); -- from second table

-- data merged by same user_id and activity_type
'2014-10-31 04:25:00', '2014-10-31 05:35:00',  '3', '1'); 

'2014-10-31 05:30:00', '2014-11-01 06:00:00',  '4', '1');
'2014-11-01 06:30:00', '2014-11-01 07:00:00',  '2', '1');
'2014-11-01 07:30:00', '2014-11-01 08:00:00',  '1', '1');
'2014-11-01 08:00:00', '2014-11-01 09:00:00',  '3', '1');
'2014-11-01 09:00:00', '2014-11-02 10:00:00',  '4', '1');
'2014-08-27 10:00:00', '2014-08-27 11:00:00',  '2', '1');
'2014-08-27 11:00:00', '2014-08-27 12:00:00',  '1', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be reduced to the question of how to combine (compact) a group of adjacent (overlapping) ranges into one. I had to deal with this some time ago and found it a bit complicated in plain SQL. There is a simple solution using loop in a plpgsql code, but I found also a general solution with the use of custom aggregate.

The function `compact_ranges(anyrange, anyrange)` returns the sum of ranges if they are adjacent (overlapping) or the second range otherwise:

```
create or replace function compact_ranges(anyrange, anyrange)
returns anyrange language sql as $$
    select case 
        when $1 && $2 or $1 -|- $2 then $1+ $2
        else $2
    end
$$;

create aggregate compact_ranges_agg (anyrange) (
    sfunc = compact_ranges,
    stype = anyrange
);
```

The aggregate has a narrow scope of usage, it should be called as a progressive window function like in the example:

```
with test(rng) as (
values
    ('[ 1,  2)'::int4range),
    ('[ 3,  7)'),  -- group 1
    ('[ 5, 10)'),  -- group 1
    ('[ 6,  8)'),  -- group 1
    ('[11, 17)'),  -- group 2
    ('[12, 16)'),  -- group 2
    ('[15, 16)'),  -- group 2
    ('[18, 19)')
)
select distinct on (lower(new_rng)) new_rng
from (
    select *, compact_ranges_agg(rng) over (order by rng) new_rng
    from test
    ) s
order by lower(new_rng), new_rng desc;

 new_rng 
---------
 [1,2)
 [3,10)
 [11,17)
 [18,19)
(4 rows)
```

In the same way you can use it for your tables:

```
with merged as (
    select tstzrange(start_time, end_time) rng, activity_type, user_id
    from first_activities 
    union
    select tstzrange(start_time, end_time) rng, activity_type, user_id 
    from second_activities
),
compacted as (
    select distinct on (user_id, activity_type, lower(new_rng))
        lower(new_rng) start_time, 
        upper(new_rng) end_time,
        activity_type, 
        user_id
    from (
        select 
            user_id, activity_type, 
            compact_ranges_agg(rng) over (partition by user_id, activity_type order by rng) new_rng
        from merged
        ) s
    order by user_id, activity_type, lower(new_rng), new_rng desc
)
select
    start_time, 
    case when end_time > lead(start_time) over w then lead(start_time) over w else end_time end,
    activity_type, 
    user_id
from compacted
window w as (order by start_time)
order by start_time;
```

The result:

```
       start_time       |        end_time        | activity_type | user_id 
------------------------+------------------------+---------------+---------
 2014-08-27 10:00:00+02 | 2014-08-27 11:00:00+02 |             2 |       1
 2014-08-27 11:00:00+02 | 2014-08-27 12:00:00+02 |             1 |       1
 2014-10-31 01:00:00+01 | 2014-10-31 02:00:00+01 |             3 |       1
 2014-10-31 02:00:00+01 | 2014-10-31 03:00:00+01 |             4 |       1
 2014-10-31 03:00:00+01 | 2014-10-31 03:30:00+01 |             2 |       1
 2014-10-31 03:30:00+01 | 2014-10-31 04:00:00+01 |             1 |       1
 2014-10-31 04:25:00+01 | 2014-10-31 05:30:00+01 |             3 |       1
 2014-10-31 05:30:00+01 | 2014-11-01 06:00:00+01 |             4 |       1
 2014-11-01 06:30:00+01 | 2014-11-01 07:00:00+01 |             2 |       1
 2014-11-01 07:30:00+01 | 2014-11-01 08:00:00+01 |             1 |       1
 2014-11-01 08:00:00+01 | 2014-11-01 09:00:00+01 |             3 |       1
 2014-11-01 09:00:00+01 | 2014-11-02 10:00:00+01 |             4 |       1
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you! How I can split intersection? To make  2014-10-31 03:00:00+01 | 2014-10-31 04:00:00+01 --> 2014-10-31 03:30:00+01 | 2014-10-31 04:00:00+01?

Comment: Splitting is easier, I've added one more stage.