# How to merge tsranges in to an array of tsranges in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I currently trying merge continuous tsranges into one tsrange, but is at the same time running into an issue in case when there is a gap between two ranges, it gets ignored..

The ranges are merged using the an `Aggregate`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE range_agg(anyrange)
(
    sfunc = range_merge,
    stype = anyrange
);
```

but problem with this is, that this skips gaps

I made an example here

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22bdbe398ecdebd7da20ed1696ec6e7a

where the outcome of the this `select range_agg(date) from DOB` is

```
["1994-03-27 00:00:00","1996-10-27 00:00:00")
```

And would have expected it to be

```
["1994-03-27 00:00:00","1995-03-26 00:00:00")
["1996-03-31 00:00:00","1996-10-27 00:00:00")
```

How do I make

Comment: Do you realy need an aggregate? You can try another aproach like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235479/postgresql-merge-and-split-date-ranges-from-two-tables-by-set-of-keys

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer
It does not return the wanted outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Since Postgres 14 you can use "multiranges"

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN

In the original anwser it is possible to replace arrays `[]` with `multirange()` and `+` to get the union of two ranges/multiranges.

## Original answer:

From: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createaggregate.html

## How to merge ranges with aggregates

- **stype** must be an array of tsranges. In the function that array must be mantained ordered and without intersections. i.e. ready to be returned
- **initcond** must be an empty array (if you want that de `range_agg` returns `[]` if no rows or leave eat undefined if you want to return `null` in that case; I suggest the first).
- **sfunc** must receive the state (the range array) and a new range. With the new range you must to iterate over the array until you find a buket or a intersecting range/s.

```sql
create or replace function range_arr_merge(arr tsrange[], new tsrange) returns tsrange[]
  language plpgsql
as 
$body$
declare 
  i integer := 1; -- array index
  k integer;
begin
  raise notice 'in % %', arr, new;
  while i <= array_length(arr,1) and lower(new) > upper(arr[i]) loop
    raise notice 'step i %', i;
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
  -- here i is beyond the end of the array or not new >> arr[i]
  -- new >> arr[j] for j<i
  k := i; -- array index to merge
  while k <= array_length(arr,1) and upper(new) >= lower(arr[k]) loop
    raise notice 'step k %', k;
    k := k + 1;
  end loop;
  -- here k is beyond the end of the array and upper(new) < lower(arr[k])
  -- from new must be merged with arr[i] to arr[k-1] 
  return arr[1:i-1] || array[tsrange(least(lower(new), lower(arr[i])), greatest(upper(new), upper(arr[k-1]))) ] || arr[k:array_length(arr,1)];
end;
$body$;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE range_agg(tsrange)
(
    sfunc = range_arr_merge,
    stype = tsrange[],
    initcond = '{}'
);

CREATE TABLE DOB (date tsrange );
INSERT into DOB (date) values 
(tsrange('1994-03-27 00:00:00','1994-10-30 00:00:00')), 
(tsrange('1994-10-30 00:00:00','1995-03-26 00:00:00')), 
(tsrange('1990-01-01 00:00:00','1990-01-02 00:00:00')), 
(tsrange('1996-03-31 00:00:00','1996-10-27 00:00:00'))
;

select range_agg(date) from DOB;
```

Living example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d20d64a8fdc91932a93080ac1731f90c

### improvements

This function can be optimized to work with ordered data by searching from end to begining (first `k` from the end of the array to de begining then `i` from `k`).

If the data are unordered, you can use bisection to search in the array.

Comment: why is the output formatted like this 
`{"[\"1990-01-01 00:00:00\",\"1990-01-02 00:00:00\")","[\"1994-03-27 00:00:00\",\"1995-3-26 00:00:00\")","[\"1996-03-31 00:00:00\",\"1996-10-27 00:00:00\")"}`
why is the output formatted as a array of strings?

Comment: It is formatted like that because that is how Postgres display arrays and display tsranges. But internally it is a array of tsranges. And you can use it as an array or as a table (using `unnest`, but that is another subject, you can ask a new question of how to use an array). The importan thing here is that you obtain the result. You can assign that to an array variable and use it.

Comment: seems to be a very heavy operation?

Comment: Yes, it is. My opinion is this: If you need this information is better to do something else. I.E. you can use the altorithm of `range_arr_merge` for iterate over a ordered recordset. In that way you may obtain realy better performance.

Comment: but still not avoid the gaps.